# "grep -R" replacement?

Tags: bash, grep, sh, replace

I have a machine with `grep` installed but option `-R` is not compiled-in and there is also no replacement switch.

How can I replace it in bash?

I tried:

```
for i in `find *`; do
    grep 'pattern' $i;
done
```

but that is not right re-interpretation, isn't it?

Comment: Did you try it?  What didn't you like about it?

Comment: @Marek — I am not sure what you don't like about this re-interpretation, but the main problem with this is that `grep` will not prefix each matching line with the filename of the match, because it only does that (at least on some Unix systems) if it is given more than one filename as input (because otherwise there is no confusion, it thinks, about where the lines are coming from). So look for a solution that provides filenames in the matching lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try piping the output of `find` to `xargs` so that `grep` only gets invoked a few times (`xargs` keeps reading input until it gets so much that more would not fit in an argument list):

```
find -type f | xargs grep foo
```

Comment: This will do the same thing as S.Lott's solution, but it won't fork a separate process to run grep each time, so it should run a lot faster.

Comment: It would be worth adding to your answer the suggestion `find -print0 | xargs -0 egrep` in case there are file or directory names containing whitespace...

Comment: Yes, file type is a concern, so `-type f` is a great addition — thanks, Mark Longair and Marc B!

Comment: Also, use `grep -H` so it'll print the filename even if there's only one file.

Comment: Another option is to include `/dev/null` as one of the files to search on every invocation; when there are multiple file names, `grep` will print the file name (even without `-H`).  `find . -type f | xargs fgrep foo /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

We usually use

```
find . -exec grep 'pattern' {} \;
```

That usually works similarly to `grep -R`.

Comment: Note that this executes `grep` *n* times for *n* files, which can be expensive if there are lots of small files, as a separate process has to be started and stopped for each one.

Comment: The proposed solution did the same.  Further, performance wasn't a requirement.  If it was, I would have written the entire thing as a few lines of Python.

Comment: `find . -type f|xargs grep 'pattern'` would solve the multiple execution problem